# Created Modal displays after click, then removes itself again

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created 2 Modals.The first modal, which is  `class = "modal"` appears as it should when add button is clicked, but when I click the "+" sign on the form to display the next Modal which is the `class = "category-modal` that modal goes back to display none for some reason.

I made a runable code:

```js
//get HTML elements username
let arrow = document.querySelector(".next");
let profSetting = document.querySelector(".prof-settings ul");
let asset = document.querySelector(".nav-side-asset");

//click event for username drop-down
arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
  arrow.classList.toggle('rotate-90');
  profSetting.classList.toggle('transform');
  asset.classList.toggle('position');
  modal.classList.toggle('modal-position');
});

//get HTML elements assets
let arrowAsset = document.querySelector(".next-asset");
let assets = document.querySelector(".assets ul");

//click event for asset drop-down
arrowAsset.addEventListener("click", () => {
  arrowAsset.classList.toggle('rotate-90');
  assets.classList.toggle('transform');
})

//Generate tag ID

//get HTML elements modal
let modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
let addbtn = document.querySelector(".add-button");
let close = document.querySelector(".close");
let background = document.querySelector(".greyback")

//click event for modal pop up
addbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  genID()
  background.style.display = "block";
})

//click event for modal remove itself
close.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.style.display = "none";
})


function genID() {
  let minNum = 0;
  let maxNum = 1000;

  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum + 1) + minNum)
  document.querySelector(".id").innerHTML = randomNum;
}

//get modal for category and department
let categoryModal = document.querySelector(".category-modal");
let categoryAdd = document.querySelector(".category-add");
let cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");


categoryAdd.addEventListener("click", () => {
  categoryModal.style.display = "block";
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--light-purplr);
}

:root {
  --dark-purple: #3B3F8C;
  --light-purplr: #4449A6;
  --light-green: #6BBF54;
  --darkish-green: #6FA656;
  --lighter-white: #F2F2F2;
  --light-white: #e9e9e9;
}

.greyback {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.7);
  width: 120em;
  height: 60.55em;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-top {
  background-color: var(--lighter-white);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15em 70em 0em;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

.nav-top ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 20vw;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.nav-top li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.nav-top li:hover {
  background-color: var(--light-white);
}

.nav-banner img {
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 14em;
  height: 3em;
}

.nav-top ul img {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.profile {
  width: 2em !important;
  height: 2em !important;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}

.nav-side,
.nav-side-asset {
  background-color: var(--lighter-white);
  width: 13em;
  height: 2.5em;
}

.nav-side ul,
.nav-side-asset ul {
  background-color: var(--lighter-white);
  position: absolute;
  height: 2.5em;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 10.5em;
}

.nav-side li,
.nav-side-asset li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.profile-side,
.asset-side {
  display: flex;
}

.profile-side img,
.asset-side img {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.profile-side p,
.asset-side p {
  margin-left: 3em;
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  position: absolute;
}

.next,
.next-asset {
  margin: 1em 11em !important;
  width: 10px !important;
  height: 10px !important;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s transform ease;
}

.prof-settings ul,
.assets ul {
  background-color: var(--lighter-white);
  padding-bottom: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.assets li {
  display: flex;
}

.assets img {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.list {
  width: 1em;
}

.add-asset {
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.in,
.out {
  width: 1.3em;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

.assets ul {
  padding-bottom: 6em !important;
}

.prof-settings li:hover,
.assets li:hover {
  color: var(--light-green);
}

.rotate-90 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.transform {
  display: block !important;
}

.position {
  margin-top: 5em;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  /*display: none;*/
  z-index: 2
}

.asset-modal-box {
  background-color: var(--light-white);
  width: 40em;
  height: 40em;
  margin-left: 40em;
}

.modal-position {
  margin-top: -5em;
}

.form {
  padding: 1em;
}

.section-left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 7em;
}

.section-right {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20em;
  margin-top: 2.1em;
}

.brand-container,
.model-container,
.serial-container {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.item-container,
.date-purchased-container,
.cost-container,
.tag-container,
.tag-container {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.description-container,
.model-container,
.serial-container,
.brand-container,
.item-container,
.date-purchased-container,
.tag-container,
.cost-container {
  display: grid;
}

.description-container {
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.tag-container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 20em;
}

.l-purchased {
  width: 8em;
}

.currency {
  background-color: var(--darkish-green);
  width: 2em;
}

.rand {
  display: flex;
  height: 2em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.rand p {
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.cost {
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
}

.item,
.brand,
.model,
.serial,
.date,
.cost,
.description,
.purchased,
.tag {
  height: 26px;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 0em 1em;
  padding-top: 12em;
}

.submit,
.close {
  margin-left: 6em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--light-green);
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.department {
  margin-left: 4.3em;
}

select {
  width: 10em;
}

.category-modal {
  background-color: var(--light-green);
  width: 37em;
  padding: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -32em;
  display: none;
}

.category-modal h3 {
  color: var(--dark-purple);
}

.line,
.line-bottom {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.line-bottom {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.category-input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 28.8em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.add,
.cancel {
  width: 4em;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--dark-purple);
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: var(--light-white);
  padding: 5px;
}

.add {
  margin-left: 33em;
}

.cancel {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.close-category {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
  margin-left: 35em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="greyback"></div>
<header>
  <nav class="nav-top">
    <div class="nav-banner">
      <img src="./references/images/CS247-Pastel-Logo (1).jpg" alt="CS247 Logo">
    </div>
    <ul class="left">
      <li><img src="./references/images/List icon.png" alt="list icon">List of Assets</li>
      <li class="add-button"><img src="./references/images/add icon.png" alt="Add button">Add an Asset</li>
      <li><img src="./references/images/Search.png" alt="Search">Search</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="right">
      <li><img src="./references/images/clock.png" alt="clock">Changelog</li>
      <li><img src="./references/images/tag.png" alt="clock">Buy Asset Tags</li>
      <li><img class="profile" src="./references/images/profile pic.png" alt="profile pic"></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>

  <aside>
    <nav class="nav-side">
      <div class="profile-side">
        <img src="./references/images/profile pic.png" alt="profile pic">
        <img class="next" src="./references/images/next.png" alt="next">
        <p>Username</p>
      </div>
      <div class="prof-settings">
        <ul>
          <li>My Profile</li>
          <li>Change Password</li>
          <li>Log out</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="nav-side-asset">
      <div class="asset-side">
        <img src="./references/images/asset-management.png" alt="Asset icon">
        <img class="next-asset" src="./references/images/next.png" alt="next">
        <p>Assets</p>
      </div>
      <div class="assets">
        <ul>
          <li><img class="list" src="./references/images/List icon.png" alt="list icon">List of Assets</li>
          <li><img class="add-asset" src="./references/images/add icon.png" alt="Add button">Add an Asset</li>
          <li><img class="in" src="./references/images/checkbox-in.png" alt="in icon">Assets In</li>
          <li><img class="out" src="./references/images/X-out.png" alt="out icon">Assets Out</li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </nav>
  </aside>

  <div class="modal">
    <div class="asset-modal-box">
      <form class="form">

        <!--Left of form inputs and labels-->
        <div class="section-left">

          <div class="tag-container">
            <label for="tag" class="l-tag">Tag ID:</label>
            <label class="id"></label>
          </div>


          <div class="item-container">
            <label for="item" class="l-item">Item</label>
            <input type="text" name="item" class="item">
          </div>

          <div class="date-purchased-container">
            <label for="item" class="l-purchased">Date of Purchase</label>
            <input type="date" name="item" class="purchased">
          </div>

          <div class="cost-container">
            <label for="item" class="l-cost">Cost</label>
            <div class="currency">
              <div class="rand">
                <p>R</p>
                <input type="text" name="item" class="cost">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Right of form inputs and labels-->
        <div class="section-right">
          <div class="brand-container">
            <label for="brand" class="l-brand">Brand</label>
            <input type="text" name="brand" class="brand">
          </div>

          <div class="model-container">
            <label for="model" class="l-model">Model</label>
            <input type="text" name="Model" class="model">
          </div>

          <div class="serial-container">
            <label for="serial" class="l-serial">Serial No</label>
            <input type="text" name="serial" class="serial">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="description-container">
          <label for="description" class="l-description">Description</label>
          <input type="text" name="serial" class="description">
        </div>

        <!--Selections-->
        <div class="options">
          <label class="category" for="category">Category
                    <select name="category" id="category" class="category">
                    </select>
                    <button class="category-add">+</button>
                </label>

          <label class="department" for="department">Department
                    <select name="department" id="department" class="department-select"></select>
                    <button class="department-add">+</button>
                </label>

          <!--Modal for select options input-->
          <div class="category-modal">

            <h3>Add Catagory</h3>
            <div class="close-category">X</div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <p>If you want to add a new category of assets, you're in the right spot. Add a category for computer equipment, wireless keyboards, or any assets you're working with.
            </p>
            <input type="text" class="category-input">
            <div class="line-bottom"></div>
            <button class="add">Add</button>
            <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Form Buttons-->
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="submit">Add Item</button>
          <button class="close">Close</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

I have attached a screenshot on what buttons to press to get to the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the code you have given and played with it. I noticed that the issue you are facing is due to the page being refreshed,  the normal behaviour when you click on a `button` inside a `form`, which you can prevent with `e.preventDefault()`. For `categoryAdd` as an example:

```js
categoryAdd.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  categoryModal.style.display = "block";
});
```

Add `e.preventDefault()` for each button that don't need to refresh the page, after passing the event `e` as parameter like I did above.